# Store two integers from a String in C

Tags: c, string, integer, c-strings

I am trying to write a program that prints two numbers from a string.

For example, string = '20,66' I am trying to break this string apart so I can store '20' and '66' into two separate variables.

Here is the code I am working on:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char line[80];

int main(void)
{
    // Variables
    int start_number, end_number;
    int i, j;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        fgets( line, sizeof(line), stdin);

        // How to find Comma
        for( i=0; i < strlen(line); i++)
        {
            if(line[i]==',') break;
        }

        // How to find two numbers
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            printf("1: %c\n", line[j]);         
        }

        for(j = i + 1; j < strlen(line); j++)
        {
            printf("2: %c\n", line[j]);
        }

        if (strcmp(line, "quit\n") == 0)
        {
            printf("Now terminating program...");
            break;
        }       

    }   
}
```

So far, I am only able to store single digit variables and for some reason prints an extra line.

Any suggestions or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a homework problem for an intro level course......

Answer (score 4):

Quite simple:

```
const char *text = "20,30";
const char *rest = 0;
int first = strtol(text, &rest, 10); // input, pointer to remaining string, base (10 = decimal)
rest += 1; // skip the comma; this is error prone in case there are spaces!
int second = strtol(rest, NULL, 10); // not interested in remaining string, so pass NULL this time
```

Answer (score 2):

One of many approaches: Once you find the comma, you can change the comma to `(char)0`. Then you will have two strings, one will be `line` the other one will be at `line+comma_offset+1`. Both are just the numbers and can be passed to `atoi`.

This trick works due to the way C strings are implemented—the end of the string is a 0. So, you take a string:

```
'1'  '2'  ','  '3'  '4'  0x00
 |
line
```

and replace the comma with a null:

```
'1'  '2'  0x00 '3'  '4'  0x00
 |              |
line            str_2
```

then you have two C strings. This is how `strtok` and `strtok_r` work.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [scanf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf) and its relatives:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int x, y;
  sscanf("22,33", "%d,%d", &x, &y);
  printf("Scanned vars: %i %i\n", x, y);
}
tmp]$ ./a.out 
Scanned vars: 22 33
```

It's possible to introduce security vulnerabilities so be sure to read and understand the section on [security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf#Security) so that you have enough storage for the values you're trying to scan.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you dont want to have "1: " and/or a NEWLINE ("\n") printed within the for loop. Change this:

```
for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    printf("1: %c\n", line[j]);
}
```

to this:

```
printf("1: "); 
for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    printf("%c", line[j]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char line[80];

int main(void)
{
    // Variables
    int start_number, end_number;
    int i, j;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        fgets( line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        for( i=0; i < strlen(line); i++)
        {
              char num[];
            if(line[i]!=','){
                num[j++] = line[i];  
            }
            else{
                for(int x =0 x<strlen(num); x++) 
                    printf("Number :%c", num[x]);
                j=0;
              }
        }
    }
}
```